# Magento2 how to access CSV file exists in var folder with website URL?

Tags: magento2, csv, export, importexport, downloadable

I am working with Magento 2.3.3 my instance is on the AWS server. On Magento2 how to access CSV file exists in var folder with website URL.

i.e. I have one file resides on **`var/export/test.csv`** now I want to access this **test.csv** file from my website URL

> - www.abc.com/var/export/test.csv

but it is always showing a **404 error: Page not found** error.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you can not access var folder.

Comment: Move `test.csv` to `pub/media` folder and access it.

Answer (score 0):

you are not authorize to access  var folder instead move the file in  websiteUrl/pub/media to access it using website url.